# Unable to display date in Arabic in VB6

Tags: date, vb6

I am trying to display date in Arabic language in VB6.
But it is showing date in English language.
I have set the following things in "Region and Language" window:

- Current language for non-Unicode programs : Arabic (Egypt),
- Format : Arabic (Egypt),
- Location : Egypt

In "*Region and Language*" window, date display correctly in Arabic.

I am using the following code to display the date in Arabic:

```
MsgBox date
```

Comment: I don't think VB6 takes those regional settings into account. If you need a special format you can use [Format$](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6) but if you need the Arabic translation of the months you have to create that your self.

Comment: I don't want to format the date, it should be printed in system default format i.e. short format (dd/MM/yyyy). I don't need Arabic translation of the months that is happening now using dd/MMM/yyyy format.

Comment: Oh, and just to be sure, VB6 is very old and no longer supported. Are you sure you're using that and not VB.NET?

Comment: Yes, I am using VB6 and not VB.NET

Comment: I am running the Windows 7 Professional, Service pack 1

Answer (score 3):

VB6 doesn't do that out-of-the-box.

If you want your date to be formatted as dd/MM/yyyy use

```
MsgBox Format$(date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

or

```
MsgBox FormatDateTime(date, vbShortDate)
```

as is explained [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6) and for ["short date"](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Manipulating_Dates_in_Visual_Basic.htm) as indicated by [Arvo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35777/arvo)

Comment: Or, if you want system default format, you can use `Format$(Date, "short date")` :)

Comment: Tnx @Arvo added that to my answer.

Comment: Format$(Date, "short date") displays the date in English format and not in the Arabic.

Comment: do me a favor and put this `WScript.Echo FormatDateTime("2012/10/10",vbLongDate)` in a file called `dt.vbs` and then execute from the command prompt `wscript dt.vbs`, let me know the outcome

Comment: wscript dt.vbs file displays the date in Arabic format...!

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1

Comment: And if you use that same `FormatDateTime("2012/10/10",vbLongDate)` in your VB6 program?

Comment: In vb6 program FormatDateTime("2012/10/10",vbLongDate) displays some part of the date(day) in English and other part of the date in Arabic.

Comment: OK, so if you use `vbShortDate` it should be in Arabic completely?

Comment: If i use vbShortDate it display hole date in English, i want it in Arabic completely.

Comment: That sounds really weird. Can you show us the short date setting from the regional settings?

Comment: did you run that application within the IDE? Or did you run it from the commandline/shortcut?

Comment: Short date format in Regional settings is dd/MM/yyyy. I am running my VB application within IDE.

Comment: Can you try compiling it and run it stand-alone

Comment: I have compiled my application and run it from IDE but same result. Also created the exe of the application and checked using running the exe by double clicking on it and also run it from command line, but same result. pls correct me if i running the exe in wrong way.

Comment: I'm really out of ideas... lets wait if someone else has some thoughts on this...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MsgBox and Format don't work for non ASCII characters.  Simple experiment.  Create a form with an edit box.  Change the edit box properties to

- (Name) NotMsgBox
- Multiline true
- Font Arial Unicode MS

  ```
  Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" ( _
      ByVal locale As Long, _
      ByVal lcType As Long, _
      ByVal lpLCData As String, _
      ByVal cchData As Long) _
      As Long
  Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
  Const LOCALE_NATIVE_LANGUAGE = &H4
  Const LOCALE_NATIVE_COUNTRY = &H8
  Function GetInfo(ByVal info As Long) As String
      Dim rv As Long, data As String
      data = String$(256, 0)
      rv = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, info, data, Len(data))
      If rv > 0 Then
          GetInfo = Left(data, rv - 1)
      Else
          GetInfo = ""
      End If
  End Function

  Function Whatever() As String
      Dim str As String
      str = ""
      str = str & "You live in " & GetInfo(LOCALE_NATIVE_COUNTRY) & vbCrLf
      str = str & "You speak " & GetInfo(LOCALE_NATIVE_LANGUAGE) & vbCrLf
      Whatever = str
  End Function

  Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim str As String
  str = Whatever
  NotMsgBox.Text = str
  MsgBox str, vbOK, "Egyptian Arabic"
  End Sub
  ```

What you'll notice is that in the Msgbox, Arabic and Egypt are in a load of jibberish but in the text box it is displayed correctly.  If you now change whatever to

```
Function Whatever() As String
    Dim str As String
    str = ""
    str = str & "Long Date is " & Format$(Now, "Long Date") & vbCrLf
    str = str & "Short Date is " & Format$(Now, "Short Date") & vbCrLf
    str = str & "General Date is " & Format$(Now, "General Date") & vbCrLf
    str = str & "Medium Date is " & Format$(Now, "Medium Date") & vbCrLf
    str = str & "You live in " & GetInfo(LOCALE_NATIVE_COUNTRY) & vbCrLf
    str = str & "You speak " & GetInfo(LOCALE_NATIVE_LANGUAGE) & vbCrLf
    Whatever = str
End Function
```

You will notice that in Long Format and Medium Format, the month appears as ?????.  It has been converted to Arabic correctly but it has then been translated back to ASCII which results in a load of ?.

What can you do about it?

- Write your own messagebox which supports Unicode
- Use ActiveX controls from FM20.dll
- Write your own date conversion routines.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but i am in same stage as application displays some part of the date(day) in English and other part of the date in Arabic, irrespective Msgbox or text box. Same result in Msgbox and Text Box with date.